# How to generate a HTML table from an asp.net model class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to dynamically generate an HTML table from a model class in ASP.NET core?

I have a class for Unit Prices which looks like this:

```
  public partial class UnitPrice
{
    public int IdProduct { get; set; }
    public int IdUnit { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Service")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("actial Price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Service Description")]
    public string DescriptionProduct { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Version")]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public int Version { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Sap ID")]
    public string Material { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Unit")]
    public UnitSpecification IdUnitNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

Unit specification looks like the following

```
    public partial class UnitSpecification
{
    public int IdUnit { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to convert the data i get when I change a version number in a drop-down.
ajax:

```
    $('#VersionSelect').change(function () {
    console.log('changed');
    var version = $('#VersionSelect option:selected').text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./UnitPrices/Version",
        data: { version: version },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        //processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if(response.length === 0)
                alert('Some error occured while uploading');

            else {
                $('#dvData').html(table);
        }
    },
        error: function (e) {
            $('#dvData').html(e.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

I have made a function that converts a Datatable to an HTML table.
When I convert my classes to a Datatable the column names aren't as they are supposed to be, and the foreign key isn't correct.
But when I use that function the column names aren't what they are supposed to be.

I want my table to look like the following:

```html
<html>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Service 
          </th>
          <th>
            Actual Price
          </th>
          <th>
            Unit
          </th>
          <th>
            Sap ID
          </th>
          <th>
            Version
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            the service name
          </td>
          <td>
            the actual price
          </td>
          <td>
            the unit name
          </td>
          <td>
            the Sap ID
          </td>
          <td>
            the Version
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

C# code:

```
    public JsonResult Version(int version)
    {
        List<UnitPrice> unitprices = new List<UnitPrice>(GetUnitPricesForVersion(version).UnitPrices);

        DataTable dt = ToDataTable(unitprices);
        //string st = CSVImportController.ConvertDataTableToHTML(dt);
        return Json(GetUnitPricesForVersion(version));
    }
    private UnitPricesViewModel GetUnitPricesForVersion(int version)
    {
        var list = _context.UnitPrice.Where(x => x.Version == version).Include(u => u.IdUnitNavigation);

        return new UnitPricesViewModel
        {
            UnitPrices = list.ToList(),
            Versions = new List<int>()
        };
    }
```

Comment: Its not clear what your issue is. You returning a `JsonResult` containing your collection in the `UnitPrices` property, so you need to loop through that and create `<tr>` and its `<td>` elements and `.append()` to the table (your `$('#dvData').html(table);` makes no sense)

Comment: Why don't you simply use public PartialViewResult Version(int version) as GET action? Create a partial view, populate it with model, and you will have then HTML content in response.